# Inconsistensies with adding 2's Complement numbers

Tags: binary

Perform the following additions of 2’s complement numbers. Indicate whether or not the sum overflows a 4-bit result.

1) 1101+0100 > I apply 2's Complement to 1101 = 0011 > 0011+0100 = 0111

So, it's -3+4 = 7

2) 1000 + 1001 > I apply 2's Complement to both = 1000+0111 = 1111 > Take 2's Complement on the answer > 0001

So, it's -8 -7 = -1

3) 0111+1000 > I apply 2's Complement to 1000 = 1000 > 0111 + 1111 = 1111 > Take 2's Complement on the answer > 0001

So, it's 7-8=1

As you can see, all the answers are wrong when double-checking with real numbers. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the 2's complement *convention* (writing negative numbers as the 2's complement of the absolute value) and the 2's complement *operation*.

Addition in the 2's complement *convention* is ordinary addition.

```
 1101
+0100
=0001 (harmless overflow)
(-3) + 4 = 1

 1000
+1001
=0001 (true overflow)
(-8) + (-7) = 1

 0111
+1000
=1111 (no overflow)
7 + (-8) = -1
```